# react-native-youtube no video sound when phone is in silent mode

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, audio, avaudiosession

I know there are similar questions, but every solution I've tried has failed, unfortunately. I'm using [react-native-youtube](https://github.com/inProgress-team/react-native-youtube) and **the sound of the videos is not playing on iOS when the phone is in silent mode**.

I tried importing `<AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>` in the beginning of `AppDelegate.m` and added this line

`[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: nil];`

at the bottom of `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` as described in their [README](https://github.com/inProgress-team/react-native-youtube#optional-activated-sound-when-iphone-ios-is-on-vibrate-mode).

I also tried enabling Audio on the Background Modes in Xcode and added audio in the Background modes in the Info.plist file.

**React Native** 0.44.3
**react-native-youtube** 1.1.0
**iOS** 11.2.2

Answer (score 0):

you can use these two lines to enable sound in slient mode

```
var Sound = require('react-native-sound');

Sound.setCategory('Playback');
```